# Better design and implementation for method with filter parameters, paging and sort ability

Tags: c#

We have `UserAcount` entity. We need `Find` method for this entity. I am usually using this pattern and implementation for such method:

```
public static List<UserAccount> Find(Dictionary<string, object> filterParams, int pageSize, int pageNumber, string sortDirection, string sortColumn, out int totalRowCount)
{
    //some code here
    StringBuilder whereCluse = new StringBuilder(" ");
    if (filterParams.ContainsKey("LifeStateId"))
          whereCluse.AppendFormat(" and f.LifeStateId = {0}", filterParams[LifeStateIdParam]);
    if (filterParams.ContainsKey("LifeCityId"))
          whereCluse.AppendFormat(" and f.LifeCityId = {0}", filterParams[LifeCityIdParam]);

    //...

    using (DatingDbContext dbContext = new DatingDbContext(DatingDbContext.ConnectionString))
    {
          totalRowCount = 0;
          var rawResult = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<UserAccount>("dbo.FindUserAccount", pageSize, pageNumber, sortColumn, sortDirection, whereCluse.ToString()).ToList();
          //do somthing else
    }             
}
```

My question is whether there is a better pattern and implementation for this method? for example using `Predicate<UserAccount>` replace for `filterParams` dictionary, or using `Expression<Func<UserAccount, bool>`. If these techniques are good, how we can use them (How we can use Predicate or Expression parameter for generating dynamic SQL (Code please)).
Such methods is very prevalent in programming. Please give me any other suggestion for design and implementation for such method.

Comment: You must have posted this question in **[codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)** :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should have posted in **[codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)**

Comment: The code as presented would be off-topic on Code Review, as stub/example code. If the OP wish to get the complete, working code for this method or class reviewed for improvements, then Code Review would be appropriate.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157497/better-design-and-implementation-for-method-with-filter-parameters-paging-and-s).